# How to solve $a \frac{d^2 y}{d x}+b \frac{d y}{d x} = f(y)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, closed-form

Let $a,b$ be real numbers and $y$ is a function of $x$.
$f$ is a given function.

How to solve the ODE :

$a \dfrac{d^2 y}{d x}+b \dfrac{d y}{d x} = f(y)$ ?

Can it be done in closed form ?

Comment: I have changed the formatting of the title so as to make it take up less vertical space -- this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions. See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9730) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future questions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Oh I see. Right sorry.

Comment: For general $f$, this is non-linear, and non-linear equation doesn't have a closed-form most of the time...qualitative analysis can be done. Any $f$ that you are interested in?

Comment: Yes. $f$ being $\ln$ and $\exp$ in particular.

Comment: @ShuhaoCao what exactly does non-linear mean here ? For b=0 there is a closed form. You mean the occurence of second derivative => non-linear right ?

Comment: @mick Hmmm....I guess we have a misunderstanding here, for example, please enlighten me how do you solve something like: $$ay'' = \ln y.$$ There is no closed form. By nonlinear I mean $f$ is a nonlinear function of $y$ resulting the whole ODE to be nonlinear.

Comment: May as well assume $a \neq 0$ (otherwise ODE is separable) and absorb $1/a$ into $f(y)$, so you would have to solve $y'' + by' = f(y)$.

Comment: If one allows integrals and solve as valid expression that does have a closed form. @ShuhaoCao

Comment: Okay, let's say for $y'' = \ln y$, letting $v = y'$ then $y(x) = \int^x_a v(u)\,du + y(a)$, your equation is now$$v' = \ln(\int^x_a v(u)\,du + y(a)).$$ Then I don't know how to proceed, I can't even separate $x$ and $v$...

Comment: If you allow the expression of $y$ contains $y$ itself (still an equation, you are not solving it), then $$(e^{bx/a}y')' = e^{bx/a}f(y)/a,$$ integrating both sides gives you: $$y'(x) = y'(0)e^{-bx/a} + e^{-bx/a}\int^x_0 e^{bu/a}f(y)/a \,du .$$ Integrating again gives you $$y(x) = y(0)+ y'(0)(1-e^{-bx/a})a/b + \int^x_0 e^{-bv/a}\int^v_0 e^{bu/a}f(y)/a \,du \,dv.$$

Comment: @ShuhaoCao In the special case $y''=F(y)$ (i.e. with $b=0$) one can integrate in quadratures (multiply the equation by $2y'$), but for $b\neq 0$ the things seem to be more difficult.

Comment: @O.L. Hmm...OP wants closed form, I doubt that it can be done. You are much better than me in finding close form, your suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

I can only suggest a partial solution for $b=0$. In this case, set $a=1$ and multiply the equation by $2y'$. It then transforms into
$$\left((y')^2-2F(y)\right)'=0,$$
where $F(y)$ denotes the antiderivative of $f(y)$. Then
$$y'=\pm\sqrt{C_1+2F(y)}\quad\Longrightarrow\quad \int\frac{dy}{\sqrt{C_1+2F(y)}}=\pm x+C_2.$$
Though we have solved the equation in quadratures, the integral on the left is very rarely computable in closed form. Essentially, $F(y)$ should be a rational function of sufficiently small degree or something reducible to that.

Comment: Well euh I was aware of that. That was basically one of the top 5 reasons I asked this more general question. Thanks for your effort though.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $a\neq0$ and $f(y)$ is a non-linear function for convenient to study the key meaning of this question.

in fact this ODE is the special case of http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/ode/ode0317.pdf.

Let $u=\dfrac{dy}{dx}$ and consider $y$ as the independent variable, you will get $au\dfrac{du}{dy}+bu=f(y)$ .

When $b\neq0$ , Let $u=\dfrac{1}{v}$ , you will get $\dfrac{dv}{dy}=-\dfrac{f(y)v^3}{a}+\dfrac{bv^2}{a}$ , which is an Abel equation of the first kind.

Then you can study http://www.hindawi.com/journals/ijmms/2011/387429/#sec2 for solving this Abel equation of the first kind analytically.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could give a small description of the links you give. (Like, does the more general case have a name?! and give author etc. when you cite a paper...) (I don't mean to be rude, but it is just I am too lazy to click a link, as are others. I need you to motivate me to click it!)

Comment: @user1729 The description of the first link is given in the post (change of the variables leading to the 1st order equation). The second link was already referenced on MSE >15 times before (which gives an idea about previous name of Harry Peter), and probably one of those links contains some details of the method. +1 anyway.

Comment: @O.L. This post came up in the review queue as a first post from a new user - I was just trying to give some friendly advice...